# Why is the Hermitian conjugate of the Fourier transform of an operator not the transform of the Hermitian conjugate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, complex-numbers

It is defined that:

\begin{align}
O(\omega)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int O(t)e^{-i\omega t} \mathrm{d}t \tag{1} \\
O^{\dagger}(\omega)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int O^{\dagger}(t)e^{-i\omega t} \mathrm{d}t \tag{2}
\end{align}
If I directly take the hermitian conjugate of equation (1) then I get:
\begin{equation}
O^{\dagger}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int O^{\dagger}(t)e^{i\omega t} \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
This result is different from equation (2). Why?

Comment: well, the obvious comment: where did Eq. 1 and Eq.2 come from? did you make them up?

Comment: yes. Do you think it is not correct?  If it is not correct, then how we transform an operator from the time domain to the frequency domain?   :)

Comment: (1) and (2) are certainly not consistent. They cant be both true, as you correcly pointed out

Comment: Thank you.  Assume Eq. 1 is true, then how should I write the fourier transform of $O^{\dagger}(t)$ ?

Comment: You forgot to change $i \rightarrow -i$ in (2).

Comment: How about the third equation you wrote? It is consistent with Eq. 1 :P

Comment: @DanielSank that's the point of the question. OP didnt forget: they are just using the same FT for both $O$ and $O^\dagger$ (Eq2 is **not** the conjugate of Eq1, its the same eq but $O\leftrightarrow O^\dagger$, as if it were valid for *any* operator)

Comment: It is interesting. I always thought fourier transform of anything has the same form.

Comment: @Mr. an of course the definition of FT is the same for any function!

Comment: This is not a question about physics, and it belongs on [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of the conjugate of a function is indeed not equal to the conjugate of the Fourier transform. Complex conjugation and Fourier transformation do not commute.

You essentially proved this, maybe it's clearer if we use a less ambiguous notation. Let
$$
\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \mathrm{e}^{-i \omega x}\mathrm{d}x
$$
$$
\hat{\overline{f}}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R} \overline{f(x)} \mathrm{e}^{-i \omega x}\mathrm{d}x
$$
As you point out, taking the conjugate of the first we obtain
$$
\overline{\hat{f}(\omega)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R} \overline{f(x)} \mathrm{e}^{i \omega x}\mathrm{d}x
=\hat{\overline{f}}(-\omega) \ .
$$

This is not so surprising if you think for example that the FT of a real function is not in general real.